# Do these two sentences mean the same thing?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say in class I'd like to ask teacher if I can use my phone because I want to look up some words.

> Can I look up words on my phone?
>
> Can I use my phone to look up words?

I want to know if they mean the same. 
Also, is there a better sentence please let me know! Because both doesn't sound very natural to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest beginning the question with "May I..." You are _able_ to use your phone in that way, but you are asking whether you are _permitted_ to do so in class.

Comment: Hi hmdol! Both are acceptable and they DO mean the same but the word 'use' in the second line makes your meaning clearer. [Because there are no words on your phone except maybe 'Samsung'!] And as Kate Bunting says, 'May' is a more polite way to ask permission.